# Cannot Compile Spring Boot Project after Update to New Version

Tags: java, spring

I updated my Spring Boot Application from 1.3.4 to 1.4.3 and refreshed the project using the Gradle Refresh.  I now have an error in my main application class:

- The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
  find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try
  building this project    BeverageDataServices Unknown    Java Problem
- The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
  referenced from required .class
  files

  BeverageDataServicesApplication.java    /BeverageDataServices/src/main/java/com/boelter/beverage

Here is the main application class:

```
package com.xxx.beverage;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication (exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, MailSenderAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxx.xxx")
@EntityScan("com.xxx.xxx.model") 
@EnableScheduling
public class BeverageDataServicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BeverageDataServicesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: These read like a Gradle compilation problem, not a Spring Boot issue.  Be sure to use JDK 8 or higher.

Comment: Do `./gradlew clean check` (on the command-line) first...you might get some other errors though.

Comment: Gradle clean works... I am getting the error in the Spring STS IDE ....

Comment: It looks like the JRE was removed or not present in the Java Build Path ... thank you both for your quick insight!!  I added the Java 8 JRE to the Build Path and it works... thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JRE was removed or not present in the Java Build Path ... thank you both for your quick insight!! I added the Java 8 JRE to the Build Path and it works... thanks